# Convert VBox or .ova to Hyper-V in 2023

Tags: hyper-v

I've seen many blogs talk about using a Microsoft Converter utility, but the link is gone, and apparently was retired in 2016-2017 time period.  I was able to export my Oracle VBOX (Virtual Box) using "Export Appliance" to a .ova (2.0) file.  I also tried a converter from StarWind, but it didn't seem to be able to take an .ova as input.

I haven't used my VBOX image (of a Windows 2019 server) for about two years, and not able to get it working on my current laptop.  I'm running Hyper-V on Windows 10.

(This is an article I was trying to follow, but it seems to be out of date: https://www.groovypost.com/howto/migrate-virtual-box-vms-windows-10-hyper-v/).

Comment: Maybe refer to this? https://superuser.com/a/1133264/132527

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I missed a step.  The .ova is really just a zip file.  I renamed it to .zip, and extracted the files inside, and then it imports into StarWind Converter - but now I have to deal with the RPC unavailable error that I'm getting.

Here's what got unzipped - use the large .vmdk as input into StarWind.

[image]

If Microsoft has a solution to converting VBOX to Hyper-V, I would like to know what that is, vs uses a third party tool.

Comment: Were you able to check their manual to convert VMDK to the VHD? These steps might help you. https://www.starwindsoftware.com/v2v-help/VMfromVMwareESXiServertoMicrosoftHyperVServer.html

Comment: Thanks, I needed to go from "local file" to "local file" and it converted, but it still won't start in Hyper-V.

Comment: How did you configure your Hyper-V VM? Try creating Gen2 VM, disable Secure Boot and attach VHDX.

Comment: @Stuka - I will have to try again in a few days, moving these files around, I've filled up my disk and need to archive some old videos first.